# Cannot execute Maven goal to build Tapestry 5.4.x from Getting started guide nor from the example source using Maven

Tags: maven, tapestry

I try to execute the Maven goal to build and run Apache Tapestry 5.4.x locally but it always failed:

**Ideas I tried:**

1. IntelliJ official Plugin arch type
2. Getting started from [tapestry.org](http://tapestry.apache.org/getting-started.html)
3. Hotel booking example from [GitHub](https://github.com/bobharner/tapestry5-hotel-booking).

**Maven / Java version**

```
tobia@FooDesktop MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**Errors**

Getting Started:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: org                                                                  .apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Lexical error,   Encountered: "\ufffd" (65                                                                  533), after : "" at archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/mybootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot[line 16, column 21] -> [Help 1]
```

Example:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/tobia/IdeaProjects/tapestry5-hotel-booking/src/main/java/com/tap5/hotelbooking/services/BasicAuthenticator.java:[87,13] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
```

For further information, please see the stracktraces attched to this: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/tscholze/e0d7498d689fdef3f71388e869f028c3).

Comment: Please don't use the java tag (see comment in my removal edits)  nor the jsf tag. Tapestry != JSF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I posted this question to the offical Mailing list. The following Maven command worked:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate \
     -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.tapestry \
     -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart \
     -DarchetypeVersion=5.4.4 \
     -DarchetypeRepository=local
```